# Using dimensional analysis to convert $oz$ to $L$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble deciding whether this table has enough information to convert between fluid $oz$ and $L$. I'm inclined to say it doesn't, but my homework problem has me considering otherwise.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what Rebecca states, a "fluid oz" is not a unit of mass but a unit of volume.  This is a critical distinction and easy to get confused about.

The way you have stated the question is ambiguous, because it is not clear if you mean "fluid oz" (the unit of volume), or "oz" (the unit of mass) of some fluid.

If it is the former, then no, that chart does not contain "fluid oz" at all.  If it is the latter, then Rebecca has given you the key to solving the problem:  you need the density of the fluid to convert between mass and volume.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot convert between [ounces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ounce) or [fluid ounces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_ounce) (units of mass) and [liters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre) (a unit of volume) without knowing the [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) of the substance.  Specifically, $$\text{density}=\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{volume}}$$ which has the unit e.g. $\text{kg}/\text{m}^3$

If you also know the density of the substance, it will be possible to convert between the two using the formula using $$\text{volume}=\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{density}}$$ but make sure the units are correct.